# Customize ResourcePicker data in shopify app development

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-app

I have started working on Shopify app. In ResourcePicker for **Product** some data is not showing which I want to see like **metaFields**. How I can see those fields. If anyone helps me out.

```
<ResourcePicker

      resourceType="Product"
      showVariants={false}
      open={this.state.open}
      onSelection={(resources) => {
          resources.selection.map((product) => {
           console.log(product)
           product.metafields
          })
      }}
      onCancel={() => this.setState({ open: false })}
                />
```

In `console.log` there is no metaField. Although if I run a query on `Shopify GraphiQL App`, it shows the metaFields exist there.

Comment: I could not see where you have write code for displaying metafield in your example

Comment: I'm not displayoing metaField, I get metaField on the basis of key and namespace, to update product metaField,  if metaField exist.